# What is the title of Sarte's essay on eye/sight/vision?

Tags: sartre

I read an essay by Sartre many years ago. It was an interesting discussion about eye, eyesight and vision. I cannot remember the details, and that's why I want to read it again. Do you know the title of such essay from Sartre?

Comment: Do you mean "The Gaze" in Being for Others in *Being and Nothingness* or are you referring to an essay about literal vision?

Comment: Seeing and Nothingness. (jk)

Comment: As far as I remember, it was about literal vision. But then again it was a long time ago so I might be wrong. I will check Being and Nothingness and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of his theory of 'The Gaze' in *Being and Nothingness* (chapter 1, section 4)? There are also many other discussions of vision and the visual field in that work. Sartre enters a park and discovers he is alone. He is at the 'still point' of the world, his self is 'focus of its visual kingdom'. But then someone else enters the park: 'the intruder himself stands at his own centre of things'. And so on.